# listing - Tabs are shown as ^^I

Tags: beamer, listings

I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175105/inserting-code-in-this-latex-document-with-indentation#3175141) to write some java code in beamer that uses the Luebeck theme.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetheme{Luebeck}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=4
}
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{frame}[fragile]
        \frametitle{Java}
\begin{lstlisting}
// Hello.java
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Hello extends JApplet {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello, world!", 65, 95);
    }    
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get the output as below.

[image: Output]

The lstlising is inside a fragile frame.
Why are all my tabs replace with `^^I` and how do I stop that from happening.

Comment: With the information you have provided so far, the issue is not reproducible. Could you therefor please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the output you get?

Comment: Hmm, I get [the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYEV8.png).

Comment: I tried pasting the MWE alone in a new file and It works perfectly.

Comment: @BBloggsbott I think you have some other settings, or some commands that change tab to `^^I` for example (though I don't know such commands).

Comment: I just noticed that the MWE uses spaces instead of tabs. When I use tabs, I get the `^^I`s again.

Comment: This problem is caused by xelatex. Either switch to pdflatex or lualatex or compile with `xelatex -8bit your_document_name`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you neither need to load the `graphicx` nor the `color` package